# UITableViewCell - How to Add Constraint to UITextView BEFORE heightForRowAtIndex is calculated

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uitextview

I currently have a `UITableView` with dynamically sizing `UITableViewCell` objects. This is based on dynamic content for a `UITextView`. This works like a charm, and I was able to get rid of my clunky and inaccurate manual implementation of `heightForRowAtIndexPath`.

Now, I'd like to give the user the option to constrain the max cell height--this is something they can turn on and off. If it's turned off, I want everything to work exactly as it does now: no requirement for me to figure out how to override `heightForRowAtIndexPath` correctly, and the cells grow to the size of the content. However, if the user turns this setting on, I want to set a max height for the row.

I can constrain the height of the `UITextView` by adding the following constraint:

```
[aCell addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:aCell.details
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeHeight
                                                  relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationLessThanOrEqual
                                                     toItem:nil
                                                  attribute:NSLayoutAttributeNotAnAttribute
                                                 multiplier:1.0
                                                   constant:[maxHeight floatValue]]];
```

Unfortunately, this happens in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, which happens *after* the size of the cell has been determined, so it seems. Either that, or it's not considering the new constraint when determining the size of the cell.

How can I constrain the height of the cell without having to override the heightForRowAtIndexPath method?

Comment: Whoever down-voted my question--how about you post a comment here about how to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using autolayout than there is no need to implement `heightForRowAtIndexpath:`

Just add this in `viewDidLoad` and set all values and constraints in `cellForRowAtIndexpath:`

```
tblView.estimatedRowHeight = 44.0;
tblView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Comment: Funny, I almost added a line saying "for completeness..." show that I was already setting those, but it's not that simple. As I said, it's dynamically sizing correctly with out the constraint. But when I add the constraint, it's not honoring the new constraint of "less than or equal to". Should it be? Is it possible I have other constrains that are keeping this from happening?

Answer (score 1):

You can try referencing your height constraint from your IB to your cell subclass and then changing its attributes (based on the configuration you provided for your user) inside your cell subclass. This will eliminate the need to add / remove constraints manually in code by just editing your referenced constraint. You can also combine the concept of setting your constraints as active or inactive in an auto-layout setup.

Answer (score 0):

No need to add constraints and get stuck in it. Just set the top, bottom, leading and trailing constraints for the text View except constraint for height. Add the function below in your view controller .

```
-(CGSize)getLabelSizeFortext:(NSString *)text forWidth:(float)width WithFont:(UIFont *)font
{
    CGSize constraint = CGSizeMake(width, MAXFLOAT);
    // Get the size of the text given the CGSize we just made as a constraint

    CGRect titleRect = [text boundingRectWithSize:constraint options:(NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin| NSStringDrawingTruncatesLastVisibleLine) attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:font} context:nil];
    return titleRect.size;

}
```

Then in tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath: you can do it such as below :-

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];
    UITextView *myTextView = (UITextView *)[cell viewWithTag:1111]; 
    CGFloat height = [self getLabelSizeFortext:description forWidth:myTextView.frame.size.width WithFont:kFontRobotoRegular(15)].height;
    return height + 5.0;  // 5.0 is the extra padding
}
```

Try it. It will definitely work. I use it always for dynamic height of my cell. Its very easy. If you have some more objects such as labels,etc. inside your cell then, while returning in `heightForRowAtIndexPath:` add their heights along with their top and bottom-constraints constants. Don't use too much padding but use can set different separate padding for iPhone and iPad devices.

Comment: This is a very constrained solution. Again, in my original question, I ask how to do this _without_ overriding heightForRowAtIndexpath. This is also seems quite inefficient from a performance perspective. I ended up changing it to a UILabel and moved on (because you can constrain the max rows with UILabel).